# Actualizar uma janela quando fecho outra

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Eu tenho uma página com uma listagem de fotos. O utilizador ao clicar em "adicionar fotos", é aberta outra aba em que o utilizador pode adicionar fotos. Mas no fim de as inserir, essa aba é fechada. O que eu queria, era que ao fechar a janela, onde adiciono as fotos a janela da listagem Actualizar-se a listagem das fotos automaticamente. É possível?

Comment: Precisamos de mais informação... as fotos são gravadas numa directoria? ou só uma referência do lado do cliente? Tem algum ajax? Como é o código?

Comment: não, é tudo guardado com jquery. O que eu quero é que ao clicar em "Fechar janela", a janela da listagem consiga actualizar-se

Comment: Existem muitas maneiras de se fazer isso, você precisa postar algumas partes do seu código, e/ou detalhar bem mais a pergunta, para que alguém consiga te orientar com clareza.

Answer (score 1):

Falta muito detalhe à sua pergunta. Vou responder de maneira relaxada com esperança que o ajude.

A minha sugestão:

HTML

```
<div id="conteudoJanela">
    <div>Adicione um url aqui:
        <input id="urlImagem" type="text" />
        <br />Exemplo: http://goo.gl/6I4zTg</div>
    <hr />
    <button type="button">Enviar</button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="abrir">Abrir nova janela</button>
<hr/>Lista de URL's
<div id="listaURL"></div>
```

javascript/jQuery

```
var conteudo = $('#conteudoJanela').html();

$('#abrir').on('click', function () {
    var win = window.open("", "", "width=400, height=200");
    $novaJanela = $(win.document.body);
    $novaJanela.html(conteudo);
    $novaJanela.find('#enviar').on('click', function () {
        var url = $novaJanela.find('#urlImagem').val();
        $('#listaURL').append(url + '<br />');
        win.close();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#conteudoJanela {
    display: none;
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/2CD2w/)

Answer (score 0):

Faz o teste utilizando esse método

```
function closeCallback() {
    //your code here
}

var openTab = function(uri, name, options, closeCallback) {
    var win = window.open(uri, name, options);
    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        try {
            if (win == null || win.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                closeCallback(win);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    }, 1000);
    return win;
};
```